# Is $Z$ a martingale?

Tags: martingales

$M$ is a continuous, strictly positive martingale.

$Z$ is defined by:

\begin{equation*}
Z(0) = 1,~dZ = \frac{dM}{M}
\end{equation*}

Clearly $Z$ is a strictly positive local martingale. Is it a true martingale?

Comment: Not strictly positive.